# how to create a dynamic variable in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a card game (blackJack) in android. the first two cards are easy card1 and card2, however i want to press a Hit me button and deal a new card and assign it to card3, card4 etc  is there any way to do this without essentially creating the maximum number of variables you would need and using if then statements to check if they have been assigned a value or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `List` to keep track of your dealt cards instead of having individual variables.

```
private List<Card> dealtCard = new LinkedList<Card>();
```

you can then add and remove your cards easily,and dynamically.

Comment: I see this code floating around, but i am not sure how to do it.  all of my code is written currently to support up to 8 decks using 4 methods

Comment: When you deal a card, just keep adding it to the list using the `add()` method. Then you won't have to keep variables like card1,card2,etc. Your list takes care of everything. To retrieve,use `get()` method. You can find many sample codes for Blackjack online,try and study them.

Comment: ok, i think i get that, and there could be two lists one for the player and one for the dealer  thanks for your help